# Draw Polygon according to an external GeoJSON file (on a server)

Tags: polygon, openlayers, geojson, layers

I'm programming a map with OpenLayers (4.6.5) and I have a GeoJSON file stored on a server and I want to use it. This GeoJSON file represents Polygons. Before I was working with Points and all was working fine, so I don't get why it's not the same thing with Polygons.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Carte Quartiers</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol/ol.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol/ol3-layerswitcher.css">
      <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
      <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
      <script src="ol/ol.js"></script>
      <script src="ol/ol3-layerswitcher.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body>

        <div id="map" class="map"></div>

          <script>

            //Layers

            {...}

            //Pictogrammes

            var piscine = new ol.style.Style({
              image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                anchor: [0.75, 46],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                src: 'image/generique.png'
              }))
            });

            //Marqueurs

            var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
              source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'my_polygon_geojson_file',
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
              })
            });

            //Vue

            var view = new ol.View({
              center: [0, 0],
              minZoom: 11,
              maxZoom: 19,
              zoom: 13
            });

            //Map

            {var map ...}

          map.addControl(new ol.control.LayerSwitcher());

          map.addControl(vectorLayer);
          vectorLayer.setStyle(piscine);

          </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong ? I have found some examples but the GeoJSON code was inside the script ...

Comment: see this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html

Comment: you may want to use a style that applies to polygon, or to use the polygon centroid (which is a point)